# Where set name of fields in belongsToMany?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have three models: `Post`, `List` and `PostList` (Pivot).
I DB I have three tables: `post (post_id, ...)`, `list(list_id, ...)`, `post_list(post_id, glist_id(In fact it's id of list))`.

I have such code:

Post -

```
public function list()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(List::class, 'post_list');
}
```

List -

```
public function stories()

{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_list');
}
```

PostList

```
   public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }

    public function list()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(list::class);
    }
```

With such code Laravel try find glist_id in PostList.

In which part of relations I must set that column in table PostList not default list_id, but glist_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

> The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you
>   are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the
>   foreign key name of the model that you are joining to.

So in your case, this would be:

```
public function list()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(List::class, 'post_list', 'post_id', 'glist_id');
}

public function stories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_list', 'glist_id', 'post_id');
}
```